# Removing multiples of 3 from number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I had a basic odd number sequence:

Where N is the number position in the sequence

```
x = n*2-1;

input
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,3,5,7,9,11
output
```

How would I go about altering this basic equation, to remove all multiples of 3 from the output?

I've tried things like
floor(x/3)*2+x  to attempt to skip the results - which works fine, but then when you get to

```
If x = 13,
floor(13/3) = 4;
4 * 2 = 8;
8 + 13 = 21;
```

^ This doesn't work as 21 is a multiple of 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Dan.

Comment: So you want a way of generating all the odd numbers that are not multiples of three?

Comment: Yes, basically. Forgive me if the tag wasn't correct - I'm not an experienced mathematician, just a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to obtain is the sequence of the numbers $k$ such that $\gcd(k,6)=1$. If you search among the first six numbers, you'ĺl find $1$ and $5$. so the sequence is
$$1,5,1+6,5+6,1+2\cdot6,5+2\cdot6\ldots$$

You can try this pseudocode:

```
for k=0 to N
   vector.append(6*k+1);
   vector.append(6*k+5);
end for;
```

Alternatively, if you do need a formula, you can try this:

```
3*k+1+(k%2)
```

Comment: I need the equation to return the result for N, without needing to iterate through all numbers prior to it's position.

Comment: I have just edited the answer to add a formula that should work

Comment: 6*k+1+4*(k%2)  // What's the % for?

Comment: Ah, modulus? Thank you, it works fine, except this seems to skip 1 at the start, whereas the following works perfectly: k=3*(k-1)+1+((k-1)%2)

Comment: If you start $k$ from $0$, then $1$ will be included.

Comment: Hmm, any idea how to then do the same with 5 and 7?

Answer (score 0):

For n = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,... the function f(n) that yields all odd outputs except the multiples of 3 is given by:

f(n) = 2*floor(3n/2)-1